# How can I edit the timestamp on remix to enable time acculation

Tags: timestamp, solidity, web3js, unix-timestamp, remix

I'm creating an application, that tracks users' listening time, and transfers a reward when they pass the average time threshold, how can I edit timestamp on remix to ease testing.

```
      function startListening() public onlyUser{
        //7DAYS = 604800 Seconds
        require(lastListeningTime[msg.sender] + weekDuration >= 
          block.timestamp, "listening session expired");

            //This checks whether a new week has started since the 
           last listening session, if yes it restarts the accumulated time
            if(block.timestamp >= lastListeningTime[msg.sender] + 
             weekDuration){
                accumulatedListeningTime[msg.sender] = 0;
            }
        lastListeningTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
    }
```